# problem of a cardinality of a union

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\lambda$ a cardinal and $\delta<\lambda^+$. I want to proof there exists a increasing chain $$\{A^i_\delta : i< cf(\lambda)\}\subseteq[\delta\times\delta]^{<\lambda}$$ converging 
to $\delta\times\delta$.

If $\delta<\lambda$ then $|\delta\times\delta|=|\delta|<\lambda$ and let 
$A^i_\delta=\delta\times\delta$ for all $i< cf(\lambda)$ and it's ok.

If $\lambda\leq\delta<\lambda^+$ then $|\delta|=\lambda$. Choose a (strictly) increasing 
sequence $\langle\alpha_\xi : \xi< cf(\lambda)\rangle$ so that $\sup(\alpha_\xi)=\lambda$ and let $\phi$ a bijection
 between $\lambda$ and $\delta\times\delta$. 
Let $B^i_\delta=\phi(\alpha_i)\subset \delta\times\delta$ for all $i< cf(\lambda)$.
 Then $|B^i_\delta|<\lambda$. But it is not necessary an increasing sequence so 
define by induction $A^i_\delta$ as follows :
$$\begin{align*}
A^0_\delta&=B^0_\delta\\
A^1_\delta&=A^0_\delta\cup B^1_\delta\\
&\vdots\\
A^{i+1}_\delta&=A^i_\delta\cup B^{i+1}_\delta&\qquad\text{successor}\\
A^i_\delta&=\bigcup_{j<i}A^j_\delta&\qquad\text{limit case}
\end{align*}$$
First, $\bigcup_{i<cf(\lambda)}A^i_\delta=\bigcup B^i_\delta=\bigcup\phi(\alpha_i)
=\phi(\bigcup \alpha_i)=\phi(\lambda)=\delta\times\delta$ and all the $A^i_\delta$ 
are subsets of $\delta\times\delta$. Second, we need to proof that the cardinality of 
each $A^i_\delta$ is $<\lambda$ : for the successor case, it's ok. But for the limit one, 
I have some problem : 
let $i<cf(\lambda)$ and consider $A:=\bigcup_{j<i}A^j_\delta$ with $|A^j_\delta|<\lambda$.
 Does $|A|<\lambda$ ? 
We have $$|\bigcup A^i_\delta|\leq\sum_{j<i}|A^j_\delta|\leq|i|.\sup|A^i_\delta|<cf(\lambda).\sup|A^i_\delta|$$
So I want to see that the last $sup$ is less than $\lambda$ (because $i<cf(\lambda)$ ?). My argument is this one :
if $\sup|A^i_\delta|=\lambda$ then, as the sequence of the $|A^i_\delta|$ is increasing, we would have a cofinal sequence in $\lambda$ of length $<cf(\lambda)$ which is not possible. Is it ok ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't the "$A_\delta^i=\delta\times\delta$ for all $i$" solution _always_ work? Is there an unstated additional assumption that you have to satisfy? (Hmm.. perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by $[~\cdot~]^{<\lambda}$?)

Comment: $[A]^\lambda$ means the subset of $A$ of cardinality less than $\lambda$.

Comment: Okay. Next question: How can the $B_\delta^i$ fail to be an increasing sequence? The $\alpha_i$'s are increasing subsets of $\lambda$, so surely their images under the bijection $\phi$ are also strictly increasing.

Comment: the bijection is not necessary an isomorphism ...

Comment: A bijection _is_ an isomorphism of sets. There's no other structure to require an "isomorphism" to preserve. The bijection $\lambda\to\delta\times\delta$ automatically lifts to an order isomorphism $\mathcal P(\lambda) \to \mathcal P(\delta\times\delta)$.

Comment: okay. So an $\alpha_i$ can be seen as an element of $\lambda$ or a subset of $\lambda$ ? For the proof, I need to consider it as a subset .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3698/discussion-between-marc-moretti-and-henning-makholm)

Comment: Yes -- since an ordinal is the set of all ordinals less than it, every element of $\lambda$ is also a subset of it (and $\alpha\le\beta \Leftrightarrow \alpha\subseteq\beta$).

Answer (score 1):

As you said, if $\delta<\lambda$ then we can just take $A_\delta^i=\delta\times\delta$.

Otherwise fix a bijection $f$ from $\lambda$ to $\delta\times\delta$, and let $\langle \xi_i\mid i<\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)\rangle$ be an increase sequence of ordinals, $\xi_i<\lambda$ for all $i$.

For every $i$ define $A_\delta^i=f''\xi_i$ is a set of cardinality $|\xi_i|<\lambda$, so $A_\delta^i\in[\delta\times\delta]^{<\lambda}$, and since for $i<j$ we have $\xi_i\subseteq\xi_j$ it follows that $A_\delta^i\subseteq A_\delta^j$. Lastly, because $\bigcup\xi_i=\lambda$ we have that $$\bigcup A_\delta^i=\bigcup f''\xi_i=f''\bigcup\xi_i=f''\lambda=\delta\times\delta.$$

As wanted.

(Where $f''X=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$, the direct image of $X$ under $f$.)